# The length of the boundary

Tags: calculus

Please I need your help if you can .

I was asked yo determine the length of the boundary which formed by the hyperbola $x^2 -81y^2=9$ and the lines $y=-2$ and $y=1$

and given the parameter representation of the hyperbola  :

$$r(t) = a\sec(t){\bf{e_x}}+b\tan(t){\bf e_y}$$

I was asked also to determine the the flux of the vector field F=(x+$x^2 y) ex + (x $y^2-y) ey through the boundary So should I use the formula ∫F(r(t)).r'(t) with t1 and t2 ?

Thank you very much .

Comment: Yes, for example $1=(\tan t)/3$ will give your $t_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much . 

you really helped me a lot .

Comment: can I ask another question in the same topic ?

Comment: I was asked also to determine the the flux of the vector field 
F=x+x^2y ex + xy^2-y ey through the boundary 
So should I use the formula ∫F(r(t)).r'(t) with t1 and t2 ?

Comment: Yes, replace $x$ and $y$ as before and integrate.

Comment: Finding length of an arbitrary hyperbola is not an elementary problem, just as it is for the case of ellipse. For a circle it is relatively easy because you are familiar with trig functions. Finding length for a right hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ would be a more reasonable problem for a calculus class, unless the text advises you to use a computer.

Comment: I may thank you a lot 
your answers are very nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1- Your equation is same as $ x^2/9- 9y^2=1$ so use $x=3 \sec t$ and $y= \tan t /3$. (Note that the equation becomes $\sec^2 t - \tan^2 t =1$, hence the justification for reparametrization.)

2- Length is $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt {(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2} dt$, now substitute and integrate. The integral however may not turn into an elementary one though!

3- Find the beginning and end of curve piece(s)  by using $y=-2$ and $y=1$ information, and determine the corresponding $t_1$ and $t_2$.

4- Report your progress back, and re-edit the question. Also tag the problem as calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your kind but do you mean that just by replacing the y=-2 and y=1 in the equation : y=tan t/3 so I can determine the t1 and t2 ?