# Flux through the sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, divergence-theorem

I have the vector field in spherical coordinates

$$ \mathbf{F} (r, \theta, \phi) = r^2\cos(\phi) \, \mathbf{e}_{\theta} $$

Why is the flux through the sphere zero?

Comment: Your field looks scalar, yet it should be vector.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the flux through a surface?  And have a look at your vector field again; it doesn't seem to be well-defined everywhere.

Comment: exactly it does not defined any where , but this is the question ,we have just this formula and we were asked to give an explanation
why the flux is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field is

$$\vec{F} = r^2 \cos{\phi} \vec{e_{\theta}}$$

As there is only a $\theta$ component of the field, then the divergence of this field is

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{F} = \frac{1}{r \sin{\theta}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin{\theta} F_{\theta}) = r \cos{\phi} \cot{\theta}$$

The net flux through the sphere is the integral of the divergence of the field through the volume of the sphere:

$$\int_0^R dr \: r^3 \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \: \cos{\theta} \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \: \cos{\phi}$$

This integral, however, is zero because the integral over $\phi$ is zero.

Comment: That's slight overkill. $\vec{e_\theta}\cdot\vec{e_r} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this nice explanation

Comment: @Rhys: for you, maybe. Not for the OP.

Comment: Well, the definition of the flux through a surface is not a volume integral.  What if they were asked to calculate the flux through the northern hemisphere?

Comment: actually the both answers are useful for me , because at first they asked us to give the reason why it is 0 ,
and then by divergence

Comment: @Rhys: then the divergence theorem would apply to the hemisphere, including flux through the disk at the boundary.  So you could use it to compute that flux, and then add back in the flux through the disk.  In  any case, you wouldn't use it if it were just easier to compute the normal component of the field over the surface.  And this is all moot, because the OP was asked to compute it over a sphere.

Comment: please can you help me also in the question 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334660/the-length-of-the-boundary
one good guy has answered me on the first part of the question but also I want the second part please which to dtermine the flux (just the idea) , 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is known as [Gauss's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) and it holds for any closed surface.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: No it doesn't; that's only for divergence-free vector fields.

Comment: it is a vector but I do not know how to put e(theta) like a symbol

So I mean just like 3i+4j+5k 
and here it is just on the e(theat)

Comment: So "e(theta)" is $e_{theta}$?  Knowing that then, I see that this field is *not* divergence-free, but the integral about its aziumuthal angle of the divergence is zero.